# Django write in database when form is submit

Tags: python, sql, django, forms

i want to use html form to be able to send back information to my view.py, the goal is to get the data, use it as arguments in a call to a stored procedure.

```
def mouvementCreation(request):
    idMI = 0
    especes = TbEspece.objects.order_by('id')
    #Get Mouvement informations

    #Connection to 'erp-site' DB 
    cursor = connections['erp-site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Produits list from Espece
        query = "{CALL SP_webGET_PRODUIT_FROM_ESPECE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)}"
        arguments = (2016, 'C', 0, 10, 'A',)
        cursor.execute(query, arguments)
        produits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Transporters list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_TRANSPORT}")
        transporters = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Livreur list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_LIVREUR}")
        livreurs = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()       

    cursor = connections['site'].cursor()
    try:
        #Get Circuit list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_CIRCUIT_FOR_MVT}")
        circuits = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Source list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_SOURCE_FOR_MVT}")
        mvtsources = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get Dest list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_DEST_FOR_MVT}")
        destinations = dictfetchall(cursor)

        #Get PontBascule list
        cursor.execute("{CALL SP_webGET_PBASCULE}")
        pontBascules = dictfetchall(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()

    reg_normes = TbRegauxnormes.objects.all()
    ordreexecs = TbOrdreexecution.objects.all()
    form = mouvementForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        pont = form.cleaned_data['pont']
        dateheure = form.cleaned_data['dateheure']
        poid = form.cleaned_data['poid']
        dsd = form.cleaned_data['dsd']
        typepesee = form.cleaned_data['typepesee']
        #Connection to 'erp-site' DB 
        cursor = connections['pontbascule'].cursor()
        try:
            #Get Produits list from Espece
            query = "{CALL SP_ADD_MANUAL_PESEE(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s,%s)}"
            arguments = (pont, '11', dateheure, poid, dsd,typepesee, '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')
            cursor.execute(query, arguments)
        finally:
            cursor.close()  
    return render(request, 'mouvementCreation.html', {'form': form, 'especes' : especes, 'produits' : produits, 'transporters' :  transporters, 'livreurs' : livreurs, 'circuits' : circuits, 'mvtsources' : mvtsources, 'destinations' : destinations, 'pontBascules' : pontBascules} )
```

The stored procedure is supposed to create a new entry.
What i want to do, but i'm not sure if possible would be :

Fill form => retrieve data in view => call stored procedure with the retrieved data => get the ID of the new entry so the user can be redirected to a another view that take the id in url parameters.

Would this be possible to do ?

Edit  : I managed to get the post request working aswell as my stored procedure, my problem is now for the last part, redirecting the user on the right page after submiting the form.

the current page is /gestion_mouvement/mouvementCreation and i want the user to be redirected on /gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/{{ID}}

Problem is it seem that the query is too slow, because by the time i submit the form the user gets redirected to /gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/
and not recieving the ID.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new cursor to fetch your last id created?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT max(id) from MANUAL_PESEE")
return {rec[0] for rec in cursor}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have that part worked out by my stored procedure that send me the last id, my problem is that at the moment, when i submit the form i get an error saying he can't find "http://localhost:8080/gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/" because in the form i have put "http://localhost:8080/gestion_mouvement/mouvementDetails/{{idCreated}}" but i think the post request redirect faster than my query execute so it end up being an url without the id and fail to reach the page.

Comment: Ok I see the point. Did you use reverse_lasy in your url declaration? "_It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded_" says [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)

Comment: I didn't, i just checked the documentation, but i don't really see how it would work in my situation, would it make it possible for the page to recieve the ID before reloading the page ? since i don't know the ID before i submit my form

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue recenly. Here is what I did.
Query concerned object model just after insert (after form.save()) and get the max(id) generated

```
form.save()
#mynewid = Msg.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0].id
mynewid = Msg.objects.latest('id').id
return redirect('/msg/{0}/edit/'.format(mynewid))
```